# Formatting Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want date with this format : `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000'`. I wrote a function but still asking myself if there is not better way to do this.
This is my function :

```
 function formatDate() {
     var d = new Date();
     var year = d.getMonth() + 1;
     var day = d.getDate();
     var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
     var hour = d.getHours();
     var min = d.getMinutes();
     var sec = d.getSeconds();
    var date = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + "-" +
         (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) +
         "T" + (hour < 10 ? '0' + hour : hour) + ":" + (min < 10 ? '0' + min : min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec) + "+0000";
     return date;
 }
```

Any ideal on how to do this with less code ?

Comment: I recommend using a library like moment.js for this.

Comment: I recommend against moment.js in this case. Your solution, while not particularly pretty (Date formatting just isn't nice to code), is going to be a hell of a lot lighter than importing even a lightweight date library.

Comment: Line 3 is not needed

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy `moment.js` is 20kb. minified and gzipped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done in one line. I made two lines to make it simpler. Combine line 2 and 3.

```js
var d = new Date(); 
date = d.toISOString().toString();
var formattedDate = date.substring(0, date.lastIndexOf(".")) + "+0000";
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/momentjs).

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTh:mm:ss+0000')
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/pegenug/edit?html,js,output)

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTh:mm:ss+0000'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var dateString = d.getUTCFullYear() +"-"+ (d.getUTCMonth()+1) +"-"+ d.getUTCDate() + " " + d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + d.getUTCSeconds()+"+0000";
```

getUTCMonth returns 0 - 11, so want to add one before you convert to string.